# Are Christians still persecuted in Afghanistan?

Tags: persecution

In the past there have been reports that Christians are persecuted in Afghanistan.

Is this still true?

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is.  **[Open Door](https://www.opendoorsusa.org/christian-persecution/world-watch-list/)** lists Afghanistan as the 4th 'worst' place in the world for Christian persecution.  While the population of Christians there is small relative to the total population, the persecution is still listed as 'extreme'.